# How to sum only the positive/negative values of the properties of objects in an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sum, inject

I understand that I can sum the properties of objects in an array in Ruby using the inject method. For example, I could sum the cash of all agents in an array using the following:

```
sum_of_cash = agents.inject(0) { |sum, e| sum + e.cash }
```

However, how can I sum only the positive or negative values of the properties, i.e. only the positive or negative cash balances, for example?

One way I can think of is doing a loop over the array and summing only if the value is positive using an if function but I'm looking for a cleaner method, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thinks that something like this is a bit more elegant

```
agents.map(&:cash).select { |c| c > 0 }.inject(&:+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a two ways that don't require an `if` inside the inject:

1. Add the appropriate method to the agent object. Then you could write the following code:

   `sum_of_cash = agents.inject(0) { |sum, e| sum + e.positive_cash }`
2. Filter before injection:

   `sum_of_case = agents.map(&:cash).keep_if{|c| c > 0 }.reduce(&:+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 agents.select{|e| e.cash > 0}.inject(0) { |sum, e| sum + e.cash }
```

Comment: note that by using `keep_if` you are destroying the original contents of `agents`. Better `select`.